# Speculaas/Biscoff cookie low calorie aroma extract

Tags: flavor

I love the taste of speculaas cookies and would like to add the aroma to foods. But one tiny cookie has ~50 kcal (~ 480 kcal/100g).

I tried mixing spices as suggested on internet but no luck.

How could I separate the fat (palm oil) and sugars from the blended cookies? How can I deemulsify the lechtins? I suppose I could add yeast for the sugar but that would take weeks right?

EDIT: Maybe the taste is partially due to caramel?

> The unique taste stems from the sugar’s caramelization during the baking process. And a hint of cinnamon and other spices add that special something. Biscoff Cookies are made with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The taste of a [Speculaas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculaas) is a lot more complex than just the spices.

So if you want to recreate it without crumbling up a cookie, you need:

- The spices:
  Probably the most obvious part, but finding the "right" mix can be a challenge. Spices vary greatly between brands and recipes, both in ratios and intensity. Where a simple recipe might use cinnamon, cloves and cardamom, others pull all stopps and also include pepper, ginger, nutmeg and possibly others. And of course "right" in this case is a matter of personal taste.
- The sugar:
  Yes, you want to save calories, but a major contributor to the flavour profile is the sugar. You need the [molasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molasses) in the brown sugar, and the [caramel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caramel), that is created during baking.
- The butter:
  Kind of obvious, but butter has its own characteristic flavour and yes, it is part of the speculaas taste. It may be easier to skip than other compounds, but when we are talking about mouthfeel and how the flavour develops when tasting a dish, it plays an important role. Many aromatic compounds are soluble in fat, not water.
- The flour:
  Part of the speculaas taste is what we percieve as "baked flavour" or "cookie" and apart from caramelization (which is covered to a greater extent by the sugar), we are also looking at the results of the [Maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction).

So if you start "building" the flavour or "removing" unwanted sugar or fat calories, you will probably end up with a meagre immitation of what you love.

Sometimes choosing the real thing and enjoying it in moderation can be more satisfying than feasting on a substitute, and in my *personal* opinion, this is one of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this recipe](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2017/06/homemade-biscoff-recipe.html), you can reproduce Biscoff's flavor.

It depends on where you live, because ingredients may vary.
Like, brown sugar in Europe is made with caramel, you have to make sure that you're using the right kind of cinnamon. Also baking soda will improve the flavor and texture of your speculaas.

Regarding the calories, it will be hard to find low calorie substitute for this type of caramel's brown sugar.